# getting individual fields from a linq query which is run from a function

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function that return a linq result :

```
  private IEnumerable<object> prepareData()
    {
        var data = from res in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(x => new
                     {
                         art = x.Field<string>("artiste"),
                         alb = x.Field<string>("album"),
                     })
                      .Select(p => new
                      {
                          album = p.Key.alb,
                          artiste = p.Key.art,
                          count_lab = p.Count(),
                          lab = p.Select(x => x.Field<string>("label")).First(),
                          filp = p.Select(x => x.Field<string>("file_path")).First()
                      })
                     .OrderBy(x => x.lab)
                   select res;
        return data;
    }
```

The query works well as designed, i can do `data = PrepareData();` and get the right results.

My issue is when i want to do a `.where` on the `data`.

if i do :

```
var album = data.Where(x => x.
```

Then i dont have any option to select a single field (it's the same if i want to do a `.Select()`).
I tried `data.AsEnumerable()` before but to no success.

I'm thinking the `IEnumerable<object> prepareData()` is the culprit, but i have no idea how to fix this (if ever it's the case).

I need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your return type is `IEnumerable<object>`, so when you use `select`/`Select()` you will only have the members of `object` available to you unless you cast to a more specific type, which you really can't do because inside `prepareData()` you are using an anonymous type for your results.

Comment: got it thanks, i suspected it was the issue, you've confirmed it :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select a single field you can use: `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`. Difference between this two is:

1. `First()` will throw an exception if an element is not found.
2. `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if element is not found.

Also if you want to fix the problem with `IEnumerable<object>` you need to create an DTO class where you can map all items from select.

Something like this:

```
public class DTOClass 
{
   public string album { get; set; }
   public string artiste { get; set; }
   public string count_lab { get; set; }
   public string lab { get; set; }
   public string filp { get; set; }
}
```

And then in select you can simply do:

```
...
Select(p => new DTOClass {
  // map the values for DTO class here
}
```

Comment: If the fields are bundled together into a type, how can `First*()` be used to "select a single field"?  And how does that relate to the question, anyways?  The question is already using `First()` with the `label` and `file_path` fields, too.

Comment: Bacon, i think it was more an advice seeing i was using the .First() option and not the other. Anyway the proposal answer was perfect :)